# New HDD: Number of Mechanical Start Failures: 6

Tags: linux, hard-disk, smartctl, badblocks

I have bought a new HDD. Toshiba P300 2TB; HDWD120UZSVA

Data sheet: https://www.toshiba-storage.com/products/toshiba-internal-hard-drives-p300/

To be sure, that this drive is in good health and will remain in good health for a long time, I decided to test it first, before using it.

I have made this:

0. the HDD is empty
1. sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sdx
2. sudo badblocks -wvs /dev/sdx
3. I have copied data of about 188 GiB to it
4. I have read some data

Now Smartctl output looks like this:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0-22-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba P300
Device Model:     TOSHIBA HDWD120
Serial Number:    22MM8L6AS
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 fdbf309cc
Firmware Version: MX4OACF0
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Oct 30 19:04:09 2022 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM feature is:   Disabled
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, NOT FROZEN [SEC1]

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84) Offline data collection activity
                    was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (14439) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 241) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     PO-R--   100   100   016    -    0
  2 Throughput_Performance  P-S---   139   139   054    -    70
  3 Spin_Up_Time            POS---   128   128   024    -    296 (Average 297)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--C-   100   100   000    -    18
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   100   100   005    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         PO-R--   100   100   067    -    0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   P-S---   124   124   020    -    33
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--C-   100   100   000    -    49
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        PO--C-   100   100   060    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    18
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    22
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--C-   100   100   000    -    22
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O----   171   171   000    -    35 (Min/Max 21/42)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O---K   100   100   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ---R--   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O-R--   200   200   000    -    0
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      1  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL     R/O      7  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x08       GPL     R/O      2  Power Conditions log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x20       GPL     R/O      1  Streaming performance log [OBS-8]
0x21       GPL     R/O      1  Write stream error log
0x22       GPL     R/O      1  Read stream error log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
No Errors Logged

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%         5         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       256 (0x0100)
Device State:                        SMART Off-line Data Collection executing in background (4)
Current Temperature:                    35 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     29/35 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     21/42 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0

SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         1 minute
Temperature Logging Interval:        1 minute
Min/Max recommended Temperature:      0/60 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:           -40/70 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    128 (20)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
  21    2022-10-30 16:57    36  *****************
  22    2022-10-30 16:58    36  *****************
  23    2022-10-30 16:59    36  *****************
  24    2022-10-30 17:00    37  ******************
 ...    ..(  8 skipped).    ..  ******************
  33    2022-10-30 17:09    37  ******************
  34    2022-10-30 17:10    38  *******************
  35    2022-10-30 17:11    38  *******************
  36    2022-10-30 17:12    37  ******************
  37    2022-10-30 17:13    38  *******************
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  *******************
  40    2022-10-30 17:16    38  *******************
  41    2022-10-30 17:17    37  ******************
  42    2022-10-30 17:18    37  ******************
  43    2022-10-30 17:19    38  *******************
 ...    ..(  5 skipped).    ..  *******************
  49    2022-10-30 17:25    38  *******************
  50    2022-10-30 17:26    39  ********************
 ...    ..( 13 skipped).    ..  ********************
  64    2022-10-30 17:40    39  ********************
  65    2022-10-30 17:41    38  *******************
  66    2022-10-30 17:42    39  ********************
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  ********************
  69    2022-10-30 17:45    39  ********************
  70    2022-10-30 17:46    38  *******************
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  *******************
  75    2022-10-30 17:51    38  *******************
  76    2022-10-30 17:52    39  ********************
  77    2022-10-30 17:53    38  *******************
 ...    ..( 17 skipped).    ..  *******************
  95    2022-10-30 18:11    38  *******************
  96    2022-10-30 18:12    39  ********************
  97    2022-10-30 18:13    39  ********************
  98    2022-10-30 18:14    38  *******************
  99    2022-10-30 18:15    39  ********************
 100    2022-10-30 18:16    38  *******************
 101    2022-10-30 18:17    39  ********************
 102    2022-10-30 18:18    38  *******************
 103    2022-10-30 18:19    39  ********************
 104    2022-10-30 18:20    38  *******************
 105    2022-10-30 18:21    39  ********************
 106    2022-10-30 18:22    39  ********************
 107    2022-10-30 18:23    38  *******************
 ...    ..(  7 skipped).    ..  *******************
 115    2022-10-30 18:31    38  *******************
 116    2022-10-30 18:32     ?  -
 117    2022-10-30 18:33    30  ***********
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  ***********
 120    2022-10-30 18:36    30  ***********
 121    2022-10-30 18:37    31  ************
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  ************
 125    2022-10-30 18:41    31  ************
 126    2022-10-30 18:42    32  *************
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  *************
   2    2022-10-30 18:46    32  *************
   3    2022-10-30 18:47    33  **************
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  **************
   7    2022-10-30 18:51    33  **************
   8    2022-10-30 18:52    34  ***************
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  ***************
  12    2022-10-30 18:56    34  ***************
  13    2022-10-30 18:57    35  ****************
 ...    ..(  6 skipped).    ..  ****************
  20    2022-10-30 19:04    35  ****************

SCT Error Recovery Control:
           Read: Disabled
          Write: Disabled

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x01  0x008  4              18  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4              49  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6     16155878806  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x020  6       122590468  ---  Number of Write Commands
0x01  0x028  6     15677407836  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x01  0x030  6       122505183  ---  Number of Read Commands
0x03  =====  =               =  ===  == Rotating Media Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x03  0x008  4              49  ---  Spindle Motor Power-on Hours
0x03  0x010  4              49  ---  Head Flying Hours
0x03  0x018  4              22  ---  Head Load Events
0x03  0x020  4               0  ---  Number of Reallocated Logical Sectors
0x03  0x028  4               0  ---  Read Recovery Attempts
0x03  0x030  4               6  ---  Number of Mechanical Start Failures
0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x04  0x008  4               0  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
0x04  0x010  4               4  ---  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion
0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x05  0x008  1              35  ---  Current Temperature
0x05  0x010  1              37  N--  Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x018  1               -  N--  Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x020  1              42  ---  Highest Temperature
0x05  0x028  1              21  ---  Lowest Temperature
0x05  0x030  1              40  N--  Highest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x038  1              25  N--  Lowest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x040  1               -  N--  Highest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x048  1               -  N--  Lowest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x050  4               0  ---  Time in Over-Temperature
0x05  0x058  1              60  ---  Specified Maximum Operating Temperature
0x05  0x060  4               0  ---  Time in Under-Temperature
0x05  0x068  1               0  ---  Specified Minimum Operating Temperature
0x06  =====  =               =  ===  == Transport Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x06  0x008  4              65  ---  Number of Hardware Resets
0x06  0x010  4              37  ---  Number of ASR Events
0x06  0x018  4               0  ---  Number of Interface CRC Errors
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0002  2            0  R_ERR response for data FIS
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0005  2            0  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x0009  2           16  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
0x000a  2            0  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x000b  2            0  CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000d  2            0  Non-CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
```

I am a bit shocked about the line

```
0x03  0x030  4               6  ---  Number of Mechanical Start Failures
```

Is this normal for a new HDD? Or should I send it back?

Comment: Send back, not normal

Comment: 1. You need to have backups of any valuable info anyways 2. I've seen HDDs with bad SMART stats (including over 50 reallocated sectors) working for more than a decade without a single issue. 3. If this value never increases, it could have been something of a rare occurrence.

Comment: OK. I have sent it back and gotten a new one. Result: Same issue: https://filehorst.de/d/eCkpwsCD // "0x03  0x030  4               6  ---  Number of Mechanical Start Failures" //; And it looks like SMART Attributes are a bit more worse than from the first HDD. (For example Spin_Up_Time: 100 instead of 128). So maybe send it back a second time?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this particular value can be safely ignored and is NOT indicative of any eminent failure.

I have a 6x2TB Raid Array with ZFS using raid2z and ECC Ram.
meaning that my filesystem does integrity checking of the data on the drives and I haven't experienced any problems with data consistency or availiability.

4 of the 6 disks in the array are the Toshiba P300 2GB.
They **ALL** have the same value as you and I cannot believe it's a coincidence.

My drives are not of the same age / batch and don't have the same uptime.
Some have been purchased with more than a year apart from older ones.